Read 4 data types..but wait for answers
I want to ask using the Serial Monitor....for
PlayerName, Age, Money, boolean Happy....
I do not know from reading around how to make the Arduino read each value...
When I do get this to partially work, on the loop around the 2nd time it does not wait for a user entry...
#code example below...but not correct anymore??? Please assist...
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop( ){
  Serial.print("Enter name: ");
  while(Serial.available( ) ==0);//wait
  String myName=Serial.readString();
  Serial.println(myName);

  Serial.print("age ");
  int age=Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.println(age);

  Serial.print("Money");
  double money=Serial.parseFloat();
  Serial.println(money);

  Serial.println("Happy (true/false)");
  bool blnHappy=Serial.read();
  Serial.println(blnHappy);
}


what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post ... also, add your code

This may help: Reading Serial on the Arduino, by Majenko.

Here is another link that may help:  https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-input-basics-updated/382007

what do you mean by Arduino Processsing App?

@jsotola The Arduino IDE (at least version 1) is based on Processing.


while(Serial.available( ) ==0);  //wait
String myName=Serial.readString();


Your while loop will wait for a single character to arrive, but you want an entire string. You need to rework somewhat.
Below is an example of doing that with a non-blocking loop to handle incoming data. Also a state machine works out what to do with the incoming message.
// the possible states of the state-machine
typedef enum {  WANT_NAME, WANT_AGE, WANT_MONEY, WANT_HAPPY, RUNNING } states;

// current state-machine state
states state = WANT_NAME;

// how much serial data we expect before a newline
const unsigned int MAX_INPUT = 50;

char name [MAX_INPUT];
int age;
long money;
bool happy;

void setup ()
  {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ("Enter your name ...");
  } // end of setup

// here to process incoming serial data after a terminator received
void process_data (const char * data)
  {
  switch (state)
    {
    case WANT_NAME:
      strncpy (name, data, MAX_INPUT);
      state = WANT_AGE;
      Serial.println ("Enter your age ...");
      break;
    case WANT_AGE:
      age = atoi (data);
      state = WANT_MONEY;
      Serial.println ("Enter your money ...");
      break;
    case WANT_MONEY:
      money = atol (data);
      state = WANT_HAPPY;
      Serial.println ("Are you happy? Y/N ...");
      break;
    case WANT_HAPPY:
      happy = toupper (data [0]) == 'Y';
        
      state = RUNNING;
      Serial.println ("Ready to play!");
      Serial.print ("Your name is ");
      Serial.println (name);
      Serial.print ("Your age is ");
      Serial.println (age);
      Serial.print ("Your money is ");
      Serial.println (money);
      Serial.print ("Your happiness is ");
      Serial.println (happy ? "yes" : "no");
      
      break;
      

    } // end of switch(state)
  }  // end of process_data
  
void processIncomingByte (const byte inByte)
  {
  static char input_line [MAX_INPUT];
  static unsigned int input_pos = 0;

  switch (inByte)
    {

    case '\n':   // end of text
      input_line [input_pos] = 0;  // terminating null byte
      
      // terminator reached! process input_line here ...
      process_data (input_line);
      
      // reset buffer for next time
      input_pos = 0;  
      break;

    case '\r':   // discard carriage return
      break;

    default:
      // keep adding if not full ... allow for terminating null byte
      if (input_pos < (MAX_INPUT - 1))
        input_line [input_pos++] = inByte;
      break;

    }  // end of switch
   
  } // end of processIncomingByte  

void loop()
  {
  // if serial data available, process it
  while (Serial.available () > 0)
    processIncomingByte (Serial.read ());
    
  // do other stuff here like testing digital input (button presses) ...

  }  // end of loop


A simpler example using more-or-less your original code is this:
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.setTimeout(100000);   // long wait for them to enter stuff
    
  Serial.print("Enter name: ");
  String myName=Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
  Serial.println(myName);

  Serial.print("age ");
  int age=Serial.parseInt();
  Serial.println(age);

  Serial.print("Money");
  double money=Serial.parseFloat();
  Serial.println(money);

  Serial.println("Happy (true/false)");
  bool blnHappy=Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
  Serial.println(blnHappy);
}

void loop( ){

}

The setTimeout call means that the readString does not terminate after one second, giving you time to type in your name, I used readStringUntil so that it waits for the newline at the end of the line. It isn't perfect, but it shows the general idea.


bool blnHappy=Serial.readStringUntil('\n');  Are you sure there's an implicit conversion from String object to bool, which results eventually in false ?


I'm not sure, and when I was testing it didn't wait for me to type true or false, so I think that part isn't working. I did mention "it isn't perfect" which was alluding to that. However getting that part right is an exercise for the reader. :)

Probably all four questions should be readStringUntil and then parse the results afterwards with atoi, atol, or atof and a string comparison for "true" or "false".

@DataFiddler I don't particularly like the parseInt etc. functions with timeouts and all that, because it takes control away from you. What happens if they don't enter an integer, for example? I would rather read a string, parse that, and then put up some sort of error if they make bad input, for example not-a-number or an empty string (no input).

That's the general issue using software: if it does not do what you need and you can't accept it, you can't use it. But you should study its behavior and perhaps you can't do it better yourself. BTW : bool blnHappy=Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); is nonsense.

@DataFiddler I've already said in a couple of comments that the line in question doesn't work. Perhaps you could post an answer that perfectly answers the question in an optimal way? Posting a good solution is more helpful than vaguely saying that my answer is wrong, in an unspecified way.
